# Disk numbering a drive then mounting in solaris 10

Tags: solaris, disk

I've a rescued sun v240 (2x 73Gb scsi drives).

Trying my best to get onto the Solaris 10 OS.

Managed to get via console lead and putty on windows machine .

Managed to get cdrom-s single user (used Solaris 10 dvd
 disc.)

Managed to get PGX64 ,type 6 keyboard and screen working .

I need some instruction on mounting the original SCSI disks .
So to vi the shadow file .
Can any one suggest the numbering I may use?

Results table of initial scan:

```
Boot device: /pci@1c,600000/scsi@2/disk@0,0:a  File and args:
SunOS Release 5.10 Version Generic_118833-33 64-bit (presume this is my DVD Disk )

Testing /pci@1e,600000/ide@d

Testing /pci@1e,600000/isa@7/rtc@0,70

Testing /pci@1c,600000/scsi@2

Testing /pci@1c,600000/scsi@2,1

Testing /pci@1e,600000/isa@7/serial@0,2e8

Testing /pci@1e,600000/isa@7/serial@0,3f8
```

So Just need the numbering to use off these scsi disks PLEASE

Comment: Try running the `format` command. It will print out a list of disks available for partitioning. Choose any disk and immediately type `quit` and it won't alter anything on the disks. There are commands within format to print out the existing partitions, or you can use the `prtvtoc` command at the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Solaris 10 OS is installed on a ZFS root pool. If so, try `zpool list and/or zpool import`. If you want to import a pool with an alternate root try `zpool import -R /alt <pool>`